# windows 8.1 uninstall programs not working

Tags: windows-8.1, storage

I am trying to uninstall some unneeded programs because my ssd is completely full. When I go to "program s and features" from the control panel and select uninstall it fails because my storage is full. Am I stuck in some catch 22?

Comment: What do you mean when you say the installation fails "*because my storage is full*?" What error message do you see?

Comment: The reported error: "An error occured while writing installation information to disk. Check to make sure enough disk space is available, and click Retry, or Cancel to end the install."

Comment: And no matter which program I choose it acts like im trying to install the program, not delete it.

Comment: As @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 suggested, you might need to make some space before you start uninstalling stuff. A good place to start is `%TMP%`. You can run this command: `explorer %TMP%` and delete everything in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for an run "*Free up disk space on this PC*"; use it to free up some space.  Then search for and run "*Free up disk space by deleting unnecessary files*", again, use it to free up some space.

If you still don't have enough space, go buy a USB key/drive and move some of your data files over to it to free up space.